# Coffeescript: how do I convert a string to a number?

Tags: coffeescript

I am building a JSON object that is sent in a POST request.
This object has properties that need to be converted from string type to integer type before sending. How does one do that with coffeescript?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use the javascript `parseInt` function.

```
number = parseInt( stringToParse, 10 );
```

Reference is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Remember, coffeescript is just javascript after it's compiled

Comment: Be careful about octal numbers when using parseInt.

Comment: Always specify the [radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix), e.g. `parseInt( stringToParse, 10 )`

Comment: this fails in one case : `parseInt('98asdfsdf',10)` , this will return `98` which is not correct at all.

Comment: @nXqd garbage in, garbage out - parseInt is made to cast strings (notation/base specified by the radix) to integers. It's impossible to know what your intention is with the cited code but if your actual purpose was to convert a hexadecimal string to an integer, you would need to change the radix, e.g. `parseInt('98asdfsdf', 16)`

Answer (score 38):

You can use the less obvious, more magical, less keyboard-intensive operator +:

```
+"158"
```

Comment: thats pretty cool! I cant find any docs on this feature, where did you learn that?

Comment: It's not a coffeescript feature, it's a javascript unary operator in the meaning of plus/minus in front of a number. Beware you can run into trouble very fast when using this: `a = true; +a++ + +(++a)`

Comment: Does alert(id +"123") and alert(id + "123") yield different results?

Comment: Also note that empty string `+""` results into zero `0`

Answer (score 7):

Javascript's parseInt function will achieve this. Remember to set the radix parameter to prevent confusion and ensure predictable behaviour. (E.g. in Coffeescript)

```
myNewInt = parseInt("176.67", 10)
```

There's a few good examples in the MDN resources: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 2):

It hasn't been documented in the official manual yet, but it seems that cast operators works too:

```
myString = "12323"
myNumber = (Number) myString
```

Comment: That isn't a cast operator, it's interpreting `(Number)` as a function (ignoring the parens) with `myString` as its argument. So it compiles to `Number(myString)`, which does have the intended effect.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend using `parseInt` since it's wrong in one case - which I found :

```
parseInt('09asdf', 10); 
#> return 09 which is not correct at all. It should return NaN
```

The correct answer should be the one from @Corkscreewe. And there is another:

```
cleanInt = (x) ->
  x = Number(x)
  (if x >= 0 then Math.floor(x) else Math.ceil(x))
```

Learn from https://coderwall.com/p/cbabhg

Answer (score 2):

Based on the link, mentioned in [nXqd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18440032/1836143), you can also implicitly convert a string by multiplying it by 1:

```
'123' * 1 // 123
```

It behaves correctly for incorrect input:

```
'123abc' * 1 // NaN
```

You can do this also with floats:

```
'123.456' * 1 // 123.456
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way for your need. NaN will be returned as expected.

```
parseInt( "09asdf".match(/^\d+$/)?[0] ? NaN,  10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
stringToConvernt = "$13,452,334.5"
output = Number(stringToConvernt.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''))
console.log(output)
//The output is `13452334.5`.
```

Comment: last line is incorrect :3
`log.console -> console.log`

Answer (score 0):

I'm always using bitwise OR to convert **strings into integers**.

```
"99.999" | 0 // returns 99
```